# gtsummary transpose levels to be displayed horizontally

Tags: r, statistics, gtsummary

#gtsummary #rstats

I was wondering if there is a way to transpose the levels to display the tables in a horizontal fashion. Meaning I want the levels displayed horizontally. I think I read all similar posts but none explained how to transpose the levels (such as quartiles) to be seen horizontally. I uploaded a reference figure. We can use `lung` as an reproducible dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)

#dataset
#call dataset:
data(cancer, package="survival")

#age by quartiles
lung %>% 
  mutate(age_q4 = ntile(age, 4),
         age_q4 = as.factor(age_q4)) -> lung

#unadjusted
fitcox.mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age_q4, data=lung)
fitcox.mod_unadj <- tbl_regression(fitcox.mod,
                                        exponentiate=TRUE,
                                        label = age_q4~"Unadjusted")
fitcox.mod_unadj

#adjusted
fitcox.mod <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age_q4 + sex + meal.cal, data=lung)
fitcox.mod_adj <- tbl_regression(fitcox.mod,
                                        exponentiate=TRUE,
                                        label = age_q4~"Adjusted")
fitcox.mod_adj

#stack
tbl_stack <- tbl_stack(list(fitcox.mod_unadj, fitcox.mod_adj))

#save to use in a word document
tbl_stack %>% as_gt() %>%  gtsave("test.rtf")
```

I can stack two tables one on top of each other and side them one next to each other, but I can't find a way to present the data horizontally. I also would like to display the results as reference table 2 given in the figure attached.

[image: Reference Desirable Output]

Comment: I think this function will be exactly what you need. https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/bstfun/reference/tbl_likert.html