# tbl_regression (gtsummary) transpose levels horizontally

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have 4 scores that I want to display horizontally with Beta estimation and 95%CI over 3 measure times. I tried a solution with tbl_likert but it's only for dataframe and not tbl object I guess.

I readed this last post on the subject : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75914079/gtsummary-transpose-levels-to-be-displayed-horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com)

In fact, I would like something as modelsummary package do with group argument :

```
library(modelsummary)

mod <- list(
  lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars),
  lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, mtcars))

modelsummary(mod, group = model ~ term)
```

I don't know how to use reprex sorry, here is part of my code :

```
## Packages 
library(tidyverse)
library(questionr)
library(gtsummary)
library(lme4)

## Loading data and describe
load("df.Rdata")
describe(df)

[618 obs. x 6 variables] tbl_df tbl data.frame

$ID: Identifiant
character: "006-002-NESJ" "006-003-AGRB" "006-005-NEKW" "006-007-VYKE" "006-008-TCHJ" "006-009-NGVE" "007-001-VPZU" "007-002-FCTW" "028-001-WFUM" "006-011-USET" ...
NAs: 0 (0%) - 206 unique values

$Source: 
character: "J0" "J0" "J0" "J0" "J0" "J0" "J0" "J0" "J0" "J0" ...
NAs: 0 (0%) - 3 unique values

$PRO_PHS11_dim: 
numeric: 68.2 81.8 95.5 75 100 70.5 90.9 97.7 100 100 ...
min: 18.2 - max: 100 - NAs: 0 (0%) - 32 unique values

$PRO_REL_dim: 
numeric: 57.1 50 100 57.1 100 67.9 92.9 100 100 100 ...
min: 10.7 - max: 100 - NAs: 0 (0%) - 23 unique values

$PRO_COG_dim: 
numeric: 45 37.5 97.5 80 80 67.5 75 50 97.5 100 ...
min: 0 - max: 100 - NAs: 0 (0%) - 37 unique values

$PRO_TRT_dim: 
numeric: 35 97.5 100 82.5 100 87.5 75 82.5 100 100 ...
min: 32.5 - max: 100 - NAs: 0 (0%) - 26 unique values

## Models
dpro_phs <- lmer(PRO_PHS11_dim ~ Source + (1|ID), data = df) %>% 
  tbl_regression(label = Source ~ "Physical dimension and symptoms")%>% bold_labels()
dpro_rel <- lmer(PRO_REL_dim ~ Source + (1|ID), data = df) %>% 
  tbl_regression(label = Source ~ "Dimension of relationships with others")%>% bold_labels()
dpro_cog <- lmer(PRO_COG_dim ~ Source + (1|ID), data = df) %>% 
  tbl_regression(label = Source ~ "Mental and cognitive dimension")%>% bold_labels()
dpro_trt <- lmer(PRO_TRT_dim ~ Source + (1|ID), data = df) %>% 
  tbl_regression(label = Source ~ "Treatment impact dimension")%>% bold_labels()

## Table 
tbl_pro <- tbl_stack(list(dpro_phs, dpro_rel, dpro_cog, dpro_trt))
tbl_pro
```

So, with this last table I had this presentation:  [raw_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGHQ7.png)

And I would like this presentation: [final_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxqpd.png)

Thank you very much

Tristan